Multiple variable names at the same time in Visual Studio?
When writing code in VS2022, I need to edit many identical variable names at the same time, can I do it later? I flashed the variable name and pressed Shift + Alt+; to mark the leftovers.

Help me check if I'm doing it right?

You can use keyboard shortcut Ctrl+R+R to rename an identifier across your project.
You may also decide if you want to replace the identifier in strings and comments as well.

